# Windows 7 - crossover connection

Tags: windows-7, networking, putty, crossover-cable

Firstly I want to say that I am not very familiar with Windows systems, usually I do my development on some Linux distribution but external factors have forced me to work on Windows system for a few months.

Now about the problem, I am developing some software on Gumstix Overo board. Before I connected to the system that is on board (http://www.angstrom-distribution.org/) using `screen` program and I also connected my computer with this board using crossover ethernet cable. The only thing that I needed to do is to statically assign IP addresses and masks on both machines.

Now on windows, I can use Putty to connect through serial interface but I am having some problems with getting crossover connection working. I can ping my board from Windows machine, but the ping from board to Windows fails, no responses are delivered to my board. I tried to disable system firewall service but it didn't help my situation.

What could I do to make my connection bidirectional (so to speak).

When I connected both machines to my local network (so both of them can access internet) I am still having the same problem. that ping from board to host fails

Comment: Have you tried using a straight cable? Most modern computers auto-sense.

Comment: That didn't help, still the same situation.

Comment: Sounds like you need to try harder to disable your firewall or whatever's blocking things on the Windows side. Since you seem to be saying you still can't ping the Windows machine even when you're not connected via crossover cable, I don't see how this is really a crossover issue.

Answer (score 0):

Quoted from [this website](http://www.sysprobs.com/enable-ping-reply-windows-7).

Reason:

> By default ICMP echo requests, used for ping command is blocked in
>   Windows 7 firewall default settings.

Solution:

> 1) Disable the firewall completely in windows 7, which is not
>   recommended.
>
> 2) Create an exceptional rule for ICMP echo request to reply ping
>   commands in existing firewall, without disabling it completely.